# F# Winforms Draw Text to a Form

Tags: winforms, f#, drawing

I am trying something as simple as drawing some text to a `Form`. There is a thousand `C#` examples out there to go from but no matter which example i seem to try and repreduce i never seem to get it right for F#.

Call me stupid but please help me anyways.

I have tried something like this:

```
form.Paint.Add(fun e -> e.Graphics.DrawString( "Hello",
                                               (System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 16)), 
                                               (new SolidBrush(Color.Black)),
                                               (System.Drawing.Point(100, 100)))
```

And lots of other attempts but all just giving errors into oblivion.

I have read there is another method called `DrawText()` what is the difference between that and `DrawString` ?

Comment: if you found C# code that suits you, then just show it

Comment: when doing that i get an error saying unexpected identifier.

Comment: Can you at least say _where_ you get the error?

Comment: I get the error in the Application.Run form. But that is not the problem since when i comment out your form.Paint.... then there is no problem.

Comment: It's a pretty simple mistake which you can easy to fix after reading the error message. So next time just write what error are you getting. In addition, I strongly recommend joining to the [F# Slack](http://fsharp.org/guides/slack/). You can also get help in [SO chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51909/f)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are confused in the data types:

```
form.Paint.Add
    (fun e -> e.Graphics.DrawString
                ("Hello", 
                 new Font("Arial", 16.0f), 
                 new SolidBrush(Color.Black),
                 PointF(100.0f, 100.0f)))
```